# Why this functional is continuous?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, problem-solving

Our functional analysis instructor assigned us a problem which is as follows:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that for each real sequence $(x_n)\to 0$ the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n$ converges.Then show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

He has also given us some hints.The hint is as follows:

Define, $T_N:c_0\to \mathbb C$ by,

$T_N(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_nx_n$ where $x\in c_0$

and apply uniform boundedness principle on the family $\{T_N\}_{N\in \mathbb N}$.

But in order to apply uniform boundedness principle our operators need to be continuous and pointwise.I have shown pointwise boundedness by observing $|T_N(x)|=|\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_nx_n|\leq B_x$ for all $N$, as the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n$ converges for each $x=\{x_1,x_2,...\}\in c_0$.But I am not able to show that $T_N$ is continuous for all $N\in \mathbb N$.Can someone give me a clue?

Comment: $|T_N(x)| \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{N}|a_n| \|x\|_{\infty}$

Comment: You need much more the just continuity of $T_N$. You have to show that $\|T_N\|=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |a_k|$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I need continuity in order to apply the uniform boundedness principle

Comment: What is $c_0$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is made up for practicing the uniform boundedness principle (the Banach-Steinhaus theorem). But it can be solved directly.

Assume by contradiction that $\sum |a_n|=\infty. $ Therefore there exists an increasing sequence of indices $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^\infty $ such that $n_1=1$ and
$$\sum_{n=n_{k}}^{n_{k+1}-1} |a_n|\ge 1,\quad k=1,2,\ldots $$
Let $a_n=|a_n|e^{i\varphi_n},$ where $\varphi_n$ denotes the argument of the complex number $a_n.$
Consider the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$
$$x_n= {1\over k} e^{-i\varphi_n},\quad {\rm for}\ n_k\le n<n_{k+1}$$
The sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $ tends to $0.$
Moreover
$$\displaylines{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1} a_nx_n\\ =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1} {1\over k}|a_n|\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty  {1\over k}=\infty}$$ hence the series $\sum a_nx_n$ is divergent.